# Create multiple temporary tables with the same name but different data paths

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a temporary table in Spark with the same name for different input sources. Below is an example.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val hr_dataframe =
  sc.textFile("/user/scvappsit/HR.txt").
     map(_.split(",")).
     map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).
     toDF()

hr_dataframe.registerTempTable("employee") //<----- employee registered

val manager_dataframe = 
  sc.textFile("/user/scvappsit/Manager.txt").
     map(_.split(",")).
     map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).
     toDF()

manager_dataframe.registerTempTable("employee") //<----- employee registered

val hr_data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM employee")
```

Now in above case if I do a `SELECT * FROM employee` it will return manager's data *instead of* HR.

I need to way to pass an alias name for the temporary table so that it won't override HR data. Below is an example.

```
hr_dataframe.registerTempTable("employee".alias("hr"))
sqlContext.sql("select * from hr")
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. The dataframe is not stored on HDFS when you use `registerTempTable`. You should probably use `df.saveAsTable` or `df.write`

Comment: This is just a pseudo code(not actual). This is just to describe my problem statement. In real applicaion , i am creating Dataframe from RDD(with Schema applied).

Comment: Can you update with a MVCE please so we can try to help ? This is not much clear to get an answer. I agree with @philantrovert otherwise. Considering the description, I'd suggest the same solution !

Comment: @eliasah Updated description with example. Hope this helps.

Comment: From logical perspective, if "manager" and "hr" employees have to exists at the same time, they are different entites, and table names have to be different.

For example, with preffixes, like "hr_employee", "mgr_employee". Exact table name have to be passed as parameter to select sql.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control on Schema side as they are provided by different team. All I have is my java spark code where i can do trick.

Comment: Spark code can be modified according to my previous comment:

manager_dataframe.registerTempTable("mgr_employee") ; 
hr_dataframe.registerTempTable("hr_employee");  

val tableParameter="hr_employee"; // or "mgr_employee"

val hr_data = sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT * from $tableParameter")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with implicts. If you add

```scala
implicit def runAlias(string: String):Alias = new Alias
class Alias {def alias(a:String):String = a }
```

you can use

```scala
hr_dataframe.registerTempTable("employee".alias("hr"))
sqlContext.sql("select * from hr")
```

and you will see the contents of `Manager.txt`. The employee table will remain unchanged, so this solution is not different from directly using

```scala
hr_dataframe.registerTempTable("hr")
```

If we a second implicit we can add some logic to `registerTempTable`:

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

import spark.implicits._
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

class Alias(var original: String, var al:String = "") {
  def alias(a:String):Alias =  {
    this.al = a
    this
  }
}

implicit def runAlias(string: String):Alias = new Alias(string)
implicit class DfOp(val df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]) {
  def registerTempTable(a: Alias): org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = {
    if( sqlContext.tableNames().contains(a.original) ) {
      sqlContext.table(a.original).union(df).registerTempTable(a.original)
    }
    else {
      df.registerTempTable(a.original)
    }
    df.registerTempTable(a.al)
    df
  }
}

val hr_dataframe = sc.textFile("/tmp/HR.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
hr_dataframe.registerTempTable("employee".alias("hr"))

val manager_dataframe = sc.textFile("/tmp/Manager.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
manager_dataframe.registerTempTable("employee".alias("mgr"))

sqlContext.sql("select * from employee").show() // prints the contents of both files
sqlContext.sql("select * from hr").show() // prints the content of HR.txt
sqlContext.sql("select * from mgr").show() // prints the context of Manager.txt
```

The first implicit will only record the original table name and the alias.

The second implicit will then take the original table and check if there is already a table with this name. If so, it will merge the currently being registered table with the existing one, otherwise it will just create a new one. After that, a second table will be created with the alias name.

After registering both tables (HR and Manager) with their respective aliases, there will be three tables:

- employee which contains rows from both files
- hr which contains the rows from HR.txt
- mgr which contains the rows from Manager.txt

Comment: Tried running your code and got

<console>:21: error: value union is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
         
          sqlContext.table(a.original).union(df).registerTempTable(a.original)
 ..

 Anything missing here ??

Comment: I tested using an IDE while I guess you are running the code as scala script on a spark-shell? I tried that as well and I got problems with some imports. I have made a few small changes in the code in my answer, and now I can start the code as script via `./spark-shell -i ../alias.scala` and it works fine. Btw: I am using spark 2.1.1 with scala 2.11.8. What versions are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.6.1

Comment: Unlike in 1.6.1, in the newer Spark versions a `DataFrame` is just a `Dataset[Row]`, so maybe replacing `Dataset[Row]` in my answer with `DataFrame` and then using `unionAll`instead of `union` will work. I am not able to test because I dont have a 1.6.1-shell. Anyhow, you should think about upgrading, as the dataframe/dataset support in 1.6.1 is lacking a lot of nice features and it is still marked `Experimental`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality to give an alias to a table name. In my opinion, you have 3 options, and that is because I don't understand your requirement. So based on your potential desire if:

1. **You want to combine all data into one table**: You union the two RDDs while still in RDD and then you register the result as a temp table

   hr_dataframe.union(manager_dataframe).registerTempTable("employee")
2. **You want it to be 2 separate tables**: Then you will need to call the one manager, and the other one employee
3. **You want them both to be called employee but still separate**: Then you will need to use a different schema name and save one table under "hr.employee" and the other table under "manager.employee". You probably need to create those schema names upfront.